# how to enable/disable a checkbox programatically in android

Tags: android, android-checkbox

I have 2 checkboxes in my app each checkbox also contains i have taken two image buttons. i want both checkbox intially disabled. if a checkbox is checked then the corresponding image button should be enabled.

Comment: Please include your efforts so far.

Comment: do a little research before asking

Comment: Whatyouhavetried(http://Whatyouhavetried.com) before asking this question , try first and then ask , if your problem is unique and new one , other will help.

Answer (score 3):

//To Disable a button

```
submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit);
submit.setEnabled(false);
```

//To Enable a button

```
submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit);
submit.setEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

use the function of checkbox.

```
 setEnabled(false)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use isChecked() , setChecked() and also setOnCheckedChangeListener() method. Please refer to this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CheckBox.html)

```
checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

  @Override
  public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked) { 

  }
}
```